# Drawing 2D stuff with SDL_Renderer and OpenGL stuff with SDL_GLContext

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, sdl, sdl-2

I have been learning about SDL 2D programming for a while and now I wanted to create a program using SDL and OpenGL combined. I set it up like this:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL and OpenGL", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
```

The program is for now just a black window with a white line displayed using OpenGl. Here is the code for the rendering:

```
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);         

glBegin(GL_LINES);     
glVertex2d(1, 0);
glVertex2d(-1, 0);
glEnd();

SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
```

So the thing is, I would like to render textures additionally using pure SDL and a SDL_Renderer object, as I did before without OpenGL. I tried that out but it didn't work. Is it even possible to do that and how? What I did is creating a SDL_Renderer and then after drawing OpenGL stuff doing this:

```
SDL_Rect fillRect;
fillRect.w = 50;
fillRect.h = 50;
fillRect.x = 0;
fillRect.y = 0; 

SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 100, 200, 100, 0);
SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &fillRect);

SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

But this does not work. The rectangle is not shown, although for some milliseconds it appears slightly. I feel like the OpenGL rendering is overwriting it.

Comment: Don't mix-n-match SDL Renderer stuff and OpenGL, down that path lies pain and madness.  At least [at this point in time](https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1138).

Comment: Ok, so it's not possible. Too bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SDL uses OpenGL (or in some cases Direct3D) and OpenGL has internal state which affects the GL calls in your program.  The current version of SDL does not clearly indicate which states it changes or depends upon for any call and it does not include functions to reset to a known state.  That means you should not mix SDL_Renderer with OpenGL yet.

However, if you really want this functionality now, you can try SDL_gpu (note: I'm the author).  It does support mixing with OpenGL calls and custom shaders.  You would want to specify which version of the OpenGL API you need (e.g. with GPU_InitRenderer(GPU_RENDERER_OPENGL_1, ...)) and reset the GL state that SDL_gpu uses each frame (GPU_ResetRendererState()).  Check out the 3d demo in the SDL_gpu source repository for more.

https://github.com/grimfang4/sdl-gpu/blob/master/demos/3d/main.c

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Does SDL_gpu support compressed textures (like DDS) without decompression at load time?

Comment: There’s not any current support (as of Jan 2018) for compressed texture formats and the format support in general is minimal.  More formats are desirable and, of course, patches are welcome if you need to make it happen sooner.

Answer (score 2):

You can render to an SDL_Surface with SDL, and then convert it to a texture & upload it to the GPU using OpenGL.

Example code: http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-tip-sdl-surface-to-opengl-texture

Comment: This answer is worth elaborating. Can you provide some short code examples? What about efficient streaming of surfaces into opengl textures?

Comment: I've been searching for nearly a day nonstop and have yet to find a complete example that works in 2021 with SDL2. Nearly every answer I've found says something similar, just render using a Surface and then convert it, etc... I wish it was documented in it's entirety.