# SDL2 Draw scene to texture. SDL2 RenderTexture like SFML

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml, sdl-2, render-to-texture

I've been developing a 2D Engine using SFML + ImGui.

[image: Here you can see an image:]

The editor is rendered using ImGui and the scene window is a [sf::RenderTexture](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1RenderTexture.php) where I draw the GameObjects and then is converted to `ImGui::Image` to render it in the editor.

Now I need to create a 3D Engine during this year in my Bachelor Degree but using SDL2 + ImGui and I want to recreate what I did with the 2D Engine.

I've managed to render the editor like I did in the 2D Engine using this [Example](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/examples/sdl_opengl3_example/main.cpp) that comes with ImGui.

[image: 3D Editor preview]

But I don't know how to create an equivalent of `sf::RenderTexture` in SDL2, so I can draw the 3D scene there and convert it to `ImGui::Image` to show it in the editor.

If you can provide code will be better. And if you want me to provide any specific code tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution.

```
SDL2window::SDL2window()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(...);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window,...);
    texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer,..., width, height);
    // create another texture for your imgui window here
    ImTexture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer,..., tex_width, tex_height);
    ...
}
void SDL2window::update(Uint32 *framebuffer)
{
    ...
    // update your main window is necessary
    SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, SDL_FLIP_VERTICAL);
    // be care of the size of framebuffer
    SDL_UpdateTexture(ImTexture, NULL, framebuffer, tex_width * sizeof(Uint32));
    ImGui::Render();
    ImGui_ImplSDLRenderer_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
void SDL2window::MyImgui()
{
    ...
    ImGui::Begin("My Texture");
    ImGui::Image(ImTexture, ImVec2(tex_width, tex_height));
    ImGui::End();
}
```

Then run `MyImgui()` in your main loop, it will work.
[ImTexture Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moqG8.png)
P.S. I like your SFML 2D engine's UI, it looks great.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Think you're looking for something like this:

```
// Create a render texture
SDL_Texture *target = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, width, height);

// Activate the render texture
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, target);

// (Do your rendering here)

// Disable the render texture
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);

// (Use the render texture)
```

Comment: I need to create a renderer for this texture? Because I don't have a renderer when I create the window. I think that SDL_GL_CreateContext is doing this. If I create a renderer I need to use the same window I used in SDL_GL_CreateContext?

Comment: @TinoTano You need a render context, yes. It's the same for SFML - just hidden and abstracted away. The texture also has to know the target, e.g. OpenGL or DirectX.

Comment: I saw some posts like this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41091875/is-sdl-renderer-useless-if-i-use-opengl-for-drawing) saying that cannot mix SDL_Renderer with OpenGL